# AWS Cognito Credentials for IoTdataClient Xamarin

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

I am having hard time with get connection to aws iot via cognito.

I'm trying to connect Authorized user to AWS IoT core with xamarin. I have succesfully added user and then get tokens from cognito user pool the problem seems to be two things:

1. my code

or

2. permissons at IAM roles or/and Cognito Federated Identities setup.

1: My code

```
var credintelas = new AnonymousAWSCredentials();
var provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(credintelas, RegionEndpoint);
CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(PoolId, AppClienID, provider);
CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser("UserName", AppClienID, userPool, provider);
string password = "Password";

AuthFlowResponse context = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
{
    Password = password
}).ConfigureAwait(false);

CognitoAWSCredentials credentials = user.GetCognitoAWSCredentials(IdentyPoolID, RegionEndpoint);
```

and then i'm passing credits to IoTdataclient like this,

```
AmazonIotDataConfig amazonIotDataConfig = new AmazonIotDataConfig();
amazonIotDataConfig.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint;
amazonIotDataConfig.UseHttp = false;
amazonIotDataConfig.SignatureVersion = "4";
amazonIotDataConfig.ServiceURL = amazonIotDataConfig.DetermineServiceURL();
AmazonIotDataClient amazonIotDataClient = new AmazonIotDataClient(credentials, amazonIotDataConfig);

string jsonString = "{ \"xxxStart\" : true, \"xxxxStart\" : false, \"xxxxStop\" : false}";
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString ?? string.Empty));

var publishreq = new PublishRequest
{
    Payload = memStream,
    Qos = 0,
    Topic = "TESTI/DEMO"

};

await amazonIotDataClient.PublishAsync(publishreq);
```

2. AWS console setup:

A) I have setup IAM Auth_role for Cognito identity and connected it to identity pool auth_role

IAM policy which is attatched to identity pool

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

B) Iot policy has been connected to cognito identity pool using AWS Cli

IoT Policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

C) Cognito User Pool has been attatched to Cognito identity pool as author provider

So what I am missing?

Comment: Same here. Have you resolved this issue?